# CheckboxGroup of JCheckBoxes

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, awt, jcheckbox

How can I make a `CheckBoxGroup` of `JCheckBox` objects? I use:

```
CheckboxGroup cg = new CheckboxGroup();
JCheckBox c1 = new JCheckBox("A", false, cg);
```

But this gives:

```
The constructor JCheckBox(String, boolean, CheckboxGroup) is undefined
```

Everything is fine if I use a regular `Checkbox` though...

Comment: Use `JRadioButton` instead and add it to `ButtonGroup`

Comment: `CheckBoxGroup` is AWT API, for Swing, you want to use `ButtonGroup`.  It doesn't, however, really make sense to use `JCheckBox` in groups as much as it does to use `JRadioButtons`...

Answer (score 2):

Look at this :

```
CheckboxGroup cbg = new CheckboxGroup();
add(new Checkbox("one", cbg, true));
add(new Checkbox("two", cbg, false));
add(new Checkbox("three", cbg, false));
```

CheckboxGroup is working with awt Checkbox. Group is the second parameter.

More: [CheckboxGroup docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CheckboxGroup.html)

Like Arvind said, it would be better to use JRadioButton